# Register Vue.js component dynamically from a string

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, compilation, http-vue-loader

I have a CRUD that enables me to write Vue.js component's code in the textarea like:

```
<template>
<div><p class='name-wrapper'>{{ model.name }}</p></div>
</template>
<script>
module.exports = {
  name: 'NameWrapper',
  props: ['model']
}
</script>
<style lang='sass'>
.name-wrapper
  color: red
</style>
```

Then in other component, I fetch this data and want to register it as a dynamic/async, custom component like:

```
<template>
<component :is='dynamicName' :model='{name: "Alex"}'></component>
</template>
<script>
import httpVueLoader from 'http-vue-loader'
import Vue from 'vue'

export default {
name: 'DynamicComponent',
props: ['dynamicName', 'componentDefinitionFromTextareaAsString'],
beforeCreate: {
  // I know that as a second parameter it should be an url to the file, but I can't provide it, but I would like to pass the contents of the file instead there:
  httpVueLoader.register(Vue, this.$options.propsData.componentDefinitionFromTextareaAsString)
  // I was trying also:
  Vue.component(this.$options.propsData.dynamicName, this.$options.propsData.componentDefinitionFromTextareaAsString)
}
}
</script>
```

As far as I know, httpVueLoader needs the url to the `.vue` file instead - is there a way to pass there the code itself of the component?

I am aware that passing and evaluating `<script></script>` tag contents can cause security issues, but I really need to do it that way.

I've read also about Vue.js compile function, but that works only for templates, not the code of the component (so the `script` tags again).

Is it even possible to achieve such functionality in Vue.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to use a `data:` URI with `http-vue-loader`, like this:

```js
const vueText = `
  <template>
      <div class="hello">Hello {{who}}</div>
  </template>
 
  <script>
  module.exports = {
      data: function() {
          return {
              who: 'world'
          }
      }
  }
  <\/script>
 
  <style>
  .hello {
      background-color: #ffe;
  }
  </style>
`

const MyComponent = httpVueLoader('data:text/plain,' + encodeURIComponent(vueText))

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  components: {
    MyComponent
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/http-vue-loader@1.4.1/src/httpVueLoader.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

If that doesn't work for some reason (maybe because one of your target browsers doesn't support it) then you could get it working by patching `httpRequest`. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-vue-loader#httpvueloaderhttprequest-url-. The documentation focuses on patching `httpRequest` to use `axios` but you could patch it to just resolve the promise to the relevant text.